# Python mint hashcash token

Tags: python, performance, cryptography

This is a Python program to mint a hashcash token, but my code is a lot slower than using a library.  What is slowing my program down?  It takes over 10 seconds to mint a 20-bit stamp, but using a library, it takes less than a second.

This is my program:

```
from os import urandom
from hashlib import sha1
import time

def mint(name, bits):
    t = time.strftime("%y%m%d")
    out = " "
    count = 0
    while out[:bits] != bits*"0":
        RandomData = urandom(8).encode("base64").replace("\n", "")
        data = "1:%d:%s:%s::%s:%s"%(bits, t, name, RandomData, format(count, 'x'))
        out = (''.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in sha1(data).digest()))
        count += 1
    return data

print mint("email_address", 20)
```

[This](http://gnosis.cx/download/gnosis/util/hashcash.py) is the library I am using for comparison.

Comment: Aside from that you're (1) using strings (and formatters all over the place) rather than numbers, and (2) rebuilding the zeros-string each iteration even though it never changes?

Comment: @cHao What do you mean it never changes? I am using `urandom`

Comment: When does `bits * "0"` ever change?

Comment: @cHao it changes when i want to adjust the collision amount

Comment: Yeah, but that's once per call.  You don't need to re-figure it each time through the loop.  And i'm pretty sure `RandomData` doesn't need to be recreated each time through either -- that's the point of `count`, to change the header so you get a different hash.  You just keep incrementing `count` (and leave the other fields alone) til you get a hash with enough zeros.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @cHao version 2.7

Comment: An optimized c/assembly implementation should be able to run in 0.15 sec or so. A good GPU will take 0.5 *milli*seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to do is to profile your code. Hashcash is really designed to make you perform 2^20 hashes: if you do more work than those hashes, something's wrong!

### Profiling

`python -m cProfile -s cumtime original.py`

Let's look at all the places where the algorithms spends more than 0.001 seconds (I've asked for 15 bits since 20 bits is too slow on my computer) :

```
   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1414287    4.087    0.000    7.665    0.000 original.py:12(<genexpr>)
  1414287    2.433    0.000    2.433    0.000 {format}
   134695    1.737    0.000    9.402    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  1346940    1.295    0.000    1.295    0.000 {ord}
        1    0.886    0.886   12.709   12.709 original.py:5(mint)
    67347    0.536    0.000    0.969    0.000 base64.py:310(encodestring)
    67347    0.432    0.000    0.432    0.000 {posix.urandom}
    67347    0.258    0.000    1.292    0.000 base64_codec.py:13(base64_encode)
    67347    0.231    0.000    1.525    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
    67348    0.141    0.000    0.141    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
    67347    0.131    0.000    0.131    0.000 {method 'digest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
   134694    0.131    0.000    0.131    0.000 {len}
    67347    0.126    0.000    0.126    0.000 {binascii.b2a_base64}
    67348    0.110    0.000    0.110    0.000 {range}
    67347    0.109    0.000    0.109    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
    67347    0.066    0.000    0.066    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 hashlib.py:55(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 base64.py:3(<module>)
```

This specific run took 12.7 seconds (original.py:5). It spent 4 seconds in the `for x in ...` generator, 2.4 seconds in `format(ord(x), '08b')`, 1.7 seconds in `''.join(...)`, and 1.3 seconds in `ord(x)`.

That's a total of... 9.5 seconds out of 12.7 seconds spent in the `out = (''.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in sha1(data).digest()))` line. This would have been impossible to figure out without profiling (as you can see in kyle k's comment). It's the number one rule of optimizations: since you'll spent 80% of your time in 20% of the code, only optimize what you know to be slow!

### Removing the 80%

So, how can we replace this line? The idea is to use `hexdigest` instead of `digest`. The issue with `hexdigest` is that we only see hexadecimal digits, not bits. Since 20 bits is 5 hexadecimal numbers, that's not an issue here. If you needed 21 bits, then you would ask for 6 hexadecimal numbers, which is more hashes than necessary, but still worth the speed up.

Here's the new code:

```
from os import urandom
from hashlib import sha1
import time
from math import ceil

def mint(name, bits):
    t = time.strftime("%y%m%d")
    out = " "
    count = 0
    digits = int(ceil(bits/4.0))

    while out[:digits] != digits*"0":
        RandomData = urandom(8).encode("base64").replace("\n", "")
        RandomData = 'AHZlx9LYMyo='
        data = "1:%d:%s:%s::%s:%s"%(bits, t, name, RandomData, format(count, 'x'))
        out = sha1(data).hexdigest()
        count += 1
    return data

print mint("email_address", 15)
```

And the new profiling:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.750    0.750    3.212    3.212 improved.py:6(mint)
    67347    0.529    0.000    0.959    0.000 base64.py:310(encodestring)
    67347    0.427    0.000    0.427    0.000 {posix.urandom}
    67347    0.251    0.000    1.274    0.000 base64_codec.py:13(base64_encode)
    67347    0.227    0.000    1.503    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
    67347    0.155    0.000    0.155    0.000 {format}
    67348    0.138    0.000    0.138    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
    67347    0.134    0.000    0.134    0.000 {method 'hexdigest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
   134694    0.131    0.000    0.131    0.000 {len}
    67347    0.122    0.000    0.122    0.000 {binascii.b2a_base64}
    67348    0.109    0.000    0.109    0.000 {range}
    67347    0.105    0.000    0.105    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
    67348    0.066    0.000    0.066    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
    67347    0.066    0.000    0.066    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 hashlib.py:55(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    3.213    3.213 improved.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 base64.py:3(<module>)
```

Yay! Only 3.2 seconds in `mint()`.

### Removing another 80%

But hashing is still not the most expensive part. It's now the computing of RandomData (0.5 + 0.2 seconds in base64 encoding, 0.4 seconds in urandom, and so on). @cHao is right, you only need to compute that RandomData once and find the count that provides the correct sha1 hash. Let's move it out of the while loop:

```
from os import urandom
from hashlib import sha1
import time
from math import ceil

def mint(name, bits):
    t = time.strftime("%y%m%d")
    out = " "
    count = 0
    digits = int(ceil(bits/4.0))
    RandomData = urandom(8).encode("base64").replace("\n", "") 
    RandomData = 'AHZlx9LYMyo='

    while out[:digits] != digits*"0":
        data = "1:%d:%s:%s::%s:%s"%(bits, t, name, RandomData, format(count, 'x'))
        out = sha1(data).hexdigest()
        count += 1
    return data

print mint("email_address", 15)
```

The new profile is:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.414    0.414    0.795    0.795 improved.py:6(mint)
    67347    0.134    0.000    0.134    0.000 {format}
    67348    0.124    0.000    0.124    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
    67347    0.121    0.000    0.121    0.000 {method 'hexdigest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 hashlib.py:55(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.796    0.796 improved.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 base64.py:3(<module>)
```

We only took 0.8 seconds (down from 12.7). `format` still takes time, but only one third of the time. I don't know what to do about it, so I'll leave it as it is, but you got your 10x speedup with two simple changes.

Comment: Constructing most of `data` before the loop, leaving only `data = prefix + format(count, 'x')` inside, shaves off further 35 % on my PC.

Comment: Yeah I had tried it but it didn't help here. Glad you got an improvement. :)